# porque no puedo instanciar mi clase en php?

Tags: php, namespace

Tengo solo 3 clases en mi proyecto, apenas estoy empezando y estoy usando la autocarga de clases con php y los namespaces.. tambien estoy empezando a entender ese tema por lo que no lo manejo muy bien. El trabajo que llevo hasta ahora me funciona muy bien en Windows, pero cuando lo llevo a ubuntu ya no puedo instanciar ni una clase. Ya comprobé que la funcion spl_autoload_register si está cargando mi clase "process" al menos.  Cuando dicha clase no tiene declarado el `namespace app\classes` me funciona correctamente. Pero en cuanto coloco la declaración del namespace obtengo error 500.. No tengo idea de que sucede. Si alguien me puede ayudar porfa se lo agradezco. Les dejo mi código que es poquito

```js
loader.php

<?php
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
$className = str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/read_xml/app/classes/'.$className.'.php');
});
?>
```

```css
PROCESS.php

<?php
namespace app\classes;
    class process {
   public $filename;
   public $doctype;
   public $file;

   public function __construct(){
   }
    function readfile() {
        $this->file->read();
    }
}
?>
```

```html
MAIN.php

<?php
include('config/loader.php');

use app\classes\process;

$process = new process();
?>
```

Les dejo tambien el mensaje del log

```html
ERROR LOG

[php7:error] [pid 1488] [client 127.0.0.1:40554] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'process' not found in /var/www/html/read_xml/config/loader.php:8\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/read_xml/main.php(2): include()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/read_xml/config/loader.php on line 8
```

Comment: Revisa el log de errores de tu servidor y compártenos el mensaje de error exacto que estás obteniendo

Comment: [php7:error] [pid 1488] [client 127.0.0.1:40554] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'process' not found in /var/www/html/read_xml/config/loader.php:8\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/read_xml/main.php(2): include()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/read_xml/config/loader.php on line 8

Comment: Agrega ese error a tu pregunta y por ahi empezar por que no logra encontrar dicha clase

Comment: ¿El fichero lo has llamado `PROCESS.php` o `process.php`? Lo normal es que en Linux ambos nombres correspondan a ficheros diferentes.

Comment: @Yohanna, en principio, la variable `$className` contiene el todo el `namespace`, es decir, `$className` seria igual a `app\classes\process`, eso quiere decir que tu función `autoload` debería estar tirando error ya que el `path` estaría mal

Comment: Gracias a todos por tomarse su tiempo en responderme. Finalmente Marcos tenía razón, en mi caso era la ruta que estaba mal. Para la próxima ya se que debo ajustar la ruta, ya que ésto no me pasa en windows.. Gracias a todos. No se como marcar la respuesta correcta..